# rsync does not respect exclude parameter copying from remote server

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync like below to copy the whole filesystem of the remote server with the hostname "beton" to a local directory. I would like to exclude virtual directories like proc, but even if I use the exclude parameter, it is still copied!

```
sudo rsync -aAXv root@beton:/ --exclude={/dev*,/lost+found*,/media*,/proc*,/run*,/sys*,/tmp*}  /mnt/big/beton_backup
```

I also tried other possibilities, but the excluded directories always get copied!

```
--exclude='/sys/*' --exclude='/tmp/*' --exclude='/dev/*' --exclude='/proc/*'
```

or

```
--exclude={/dev,/lost+found,/media,/mnt,/proc,/run,/sys,/tmp}
```

It's a problem because /proc is like 64TB, and I don't want to copy it!